# How to call AWS Athena Rest APIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'm getting the following error:

> com.amazon.coral.service#UnknownOperationException

not sure what's the issue?

postman call

[image]

postman variables

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess - put the `&version=` in the URL, not in the variable or the `&` will get escaped.

`&` is converted to `&amp;` in variables so `action` would contain  `GetDatabase&amp;Version=2016-11-15` instead of `GetDatabase` and `version` would not be set.

Your URL should probably end with `?Action={{Action}}&Version={{version}}` and your version variable would just be the date

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did the changes and still getting the same error.